# Eigenvectors 2x2

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have matrix $ \begin{bmatrix}
 1&0 \\ 
 4&1 
\end{bmatrix} $ with repeated eigenvalue of 1. How do I find the eigenvectors? All I seem to get is 
$ \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix} $

Comment: How have you been trying to find the eigenvectors?

Comment: With $ (A - I\lambda )X = 0 $

Comment: You should first compute the roots of the characteristic polynomial $\det(A-\lambda I)$, which are the eigenvalues, and then for each eigenvalue solve $(A-\lambda I)x=0$.

Comment: I'm confused - that's what I've been doing I think? I found the repeated eigenvalue with $ det(A - \lambda I) $ then solved for X with $ (A - I\lambda )X = 0 $ and got [0 0]T

Comment: Ah, I missed that you mentioned the eigenvalue. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

- You cannot have a zero eigenvector.
- To find the first eigenvector, we setup and find the RREF of $[A - I]v_1 = 0$. This should yield an eigenvector $v_1 = (0,1)$.
- We can only get one linearly independent eigenvector from this last step, so set up and solve $[A- I]v_2 = v_1$. This yields a second eigenvector of $v_2 = (\frac{1}{4},0)$.

Comment: What are you doing in the 3rd bullet point?  This isn't a diagonal matrix, so you can't have everything be an eigenvector (implied by 2 linearly independent eigenvectors).

Comment: It is a generalized eigenvector. Also, what in the world are you talking about? We have a repeated eigenvalue and need two independent eigenvectors. Why are you talking about diagonal matrices?

Comment: It would be nice if the down voter would explain why they are down voting a correct answer. Obviously this problem is too complicated for them if they cannot understand this very simple system.

Comment: How did you get $ v_1 $ ? $ (A - I) =  \begin{bmatrix}
 0&0 \\ 
 4&0 
\end{bmatrix} $, so $ 4v_{11} + 0v_{21} = 0 $ so therefore $ v_{11} = v_{21} = 0 $ or have I missed something?

Comment: Recall, you cannot have a zero eigenvector. So, divide the second row by 4. We now have $x + 0 y = 0$. You can choose $x = 0, y = 1$ to get an eigenvector. Clear? Note, you used $v_1$ and $v_2$ for the variables.

Comment: Oh of course! I did not see that. Thank you Amzoti!

Comment: Someone down voted this correct answer as it is beyond them. Also, look at the second eigenvector - for a linearly independent one. Glad I could help.

Comment: Oh, I was confused because I'm not used to generalized eigenvectors being a subset of eigenvectors.

Comment: @mathematician so if you downvoted, you should think about removing it. Amzoti, maybe you edit your answer to make it possible...

Comment: There is nothing to edit, my answer was correct from the get go!

Comment: @amWhy: Thank you! The talk went great. People were sending nice emails today and asking for copies of my slides. I was so wiped out, just woke up from a nap. Someone DV this post as being wrong and it was correct the entire time. That is more frustrating than anything!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $(x_1,x_2)^{T}$ is an eigenvector, then
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\4&1\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\end{array}\right]$$
The system of equation reduces to $$\begin{eqnarray*}x_1&=&x_1\\4x_1+x_2&=&x_2\end{eqnarray*}$$
From the second equation we get $x_1=0$ and $x_2$ can be any real. Thus the eigenvectors corresponding to $1$ will look like $(0,x)^{T}$.

Comment: I haven't seen that first step before where you have $ AX=X $, I usually solve eigenvectors with $ (A - I\lambda )X = 0 $. I don't understand why you haven't taken away the identity eigenvalue matrix away from A but also equated it to X?

Comment: Solving for $(A-I)X=0$ and solving $AX=X$ is the same thing!